# Django Model matching query does not exist on newly created instances

Tags: python, django

So I been seeing the same question posted in different scenarios and I am unable to get mine to work. Basically trying to find a model instance if it already exists and create a new one if it doesn't - based on if the instance have the same field as the user's username

I tried get_object_or_404 and even changing the primary key to a field in the model class.

this is the models.py

```py
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, user):
        user = cls(user=user)

        return user

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return f'{self.id} {self.user}'
```

this is the views.py

```py
def cart(request, pk):
    try:
        pizza = PizzaInstance.objects.get(id=pk)
        # get the topping(s)
        topping_1 = int(request.POST["topping1"])
        topping = PizzaTopping.objects.get(pk=topping_1)
        # get the username
        user = request.user.username
        # check if the user already has an order
        try:
            order = Cart.objects.get(user=user)
        except KeyError:
            order = Cart.create([user])
            order.save()
```

user creation

```py
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

I expected to see the order being saved and a new instance being created or even new instances added to the cart.

error is get is -
Cart matching query does not exist.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of problems:

1. You should retrieve the user with `request.user` instead of `request.user.username` (the latter gives you the username which is a `str` instead of the `User` instance.
2. You shouldn't really create your objects with a custom class method. Instead, use the object manager and call `Cart.objects.create(user=user)` (and if you *do* need to make a custom `create()` function, it should be defined on a custom manager class).

With these changes you should be able to use `Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=user)`, which returns a tuple containing your `Cart` object and a `bool` indicating wether the object was created or not (ie. existed in the first place).

So put together:

```py
def cart(request, pk):
    try:
        pizza = PizzaInstance.objects.get(id=pk)
        # get the topping(s)
        topping_1 = int(request.POST["topping1"])
        topping = PizzaTopping.objects.get(pk=topping_1)

        # get the user
        user = request.user

        # get the Cart object associated with 'user' or create a new one
        order, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
```

Comment: ok so that means my add is no longer working as now it is a tuple, 

int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Cart'

what's the correct syntax to access the tuple's pk for my add method to work now?

Comment: I don't know what 'add' you are referring to. But if you write `cart, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=user)` then you will have access to your `Cart` object in the `cart` variable (which you seem to call `order` in your code).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`.get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) method:

```
cart, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing some odd things here.

`Cart.objects.get` won't raise a KeyError. It raises the error you see: Cart.DoesNotExist. So that is the error you need to catch.

Additionally, for some reason you are wrapping the `user` in a list when you pass it in the except block. Don't do that.

```
    try:
        order = Cart.objects.get(user=user)
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        order = Cart.create(user)
        order.save()
```

Comment: I couldn't add the user without the square brackets when I created the user via Django auth contrib library. 
Now I am getting this error using the above code -
NOT NULL constraint failed: orders_cart.id

does that mean I have to set a not_null=True for something?

Comment: Did you define an `id` field in your model definition? Your code doesn't show that you did, and you don't need to. But if you did, please show the actual model definition.

Comment: No, I didn't add an id field in the model definition. The following code <user = request.user.username> returns ['user1'] if I print it out and in the admin page of django shows that as well. I have updated the main post to show how the user is created.